# Why doesn't the const lvalue reference to an array compile below?

Tags: c++, arrays, reference

The const lvalue reference `int(const& crb)[3] = b;` doesn't compile. Why?

```
#include<iostream>

int a = 1;
int b[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };

int main(){
    int& ra = a;             // Ok
    int const& cra = a;      // Ok

    int(&rb)[3] = b;         // Ok
    int(const& crb)[3] = b;   // Doesn't compile
}
```

Error message emitted by g++:

```
error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
int(const& crb)[3] = b;
^~~
```

Comment: `int const (& crb)[3] = b;`

Comment: @VTT This is not a const reference.

Comment: It is a reference to const items. Note that `cra` is not a const reference either, it is a reference to const int item. If `const` qualifier was allowed on references themselves (it is not allowed) syntax for const reference would be `int const & const cr = a;`

Comment: @JoãoAfonso I'm not sure what you mean by "that's not a const reference". Once initialized, a reference is already const; it cannot be changed to reference something else. I think you're trying to get a *reference to const <blah>*, and in that, your syntax is simply wrong, as VTT pointed out.

Comment: Why not use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of a C-style array?

Comment: @VIT and WhozCraig You are both right. I'm tired already. Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: @JesperJuhl because it has *nothing* to do with his question. The OP is no-doubt studying const/volatile type modifiers, and ran into this problem with his syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Reference is always constant, you can't change reference. `int const (& crb)[3] = b;` here we have reference to array of const int, we can also write  `const int (& crb)[3] = b;` It would be the same.

Pointers have a difference, pointer can be changed

`const int *p;` - here it is pointer on const int

`int const *p;` - here it is const pointer on int

`const int const *p;` - here it is const pointer on const int